# Linux giving permission to an user to the log file

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

Using SFTP I want to copy the `log` directory from `var`.

By default my user have permission denied without `sudo`. Root is blocked for login, besides I don't want to use it in sftp.

I want to give my user permission to `log` directory without needing `sudo`.

so being in `var` I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R u+r log
```

no error back, but still no permission on sftp

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `chmod` manpage the following command sets the readable permission to owner user :

```
sudo chmod -R u+r log
```

To set readable permission to all users use instead:

```
sudo chmod -R o+r log
```

However, I would recommand using ACLs to avoid anyone can read (which can be a security concern). Assuming your user login is `mylogin`, you could use:

```
setfacl -R -m u:mylogin:rX log
```

- `-R` : recursive action
- `-m u:mylogin:rX` : grants access to user `mylogin`

To remove this ACL, use:

```
setfacl -R -x u:mylogin:r log
```

Comment: the first command removed my listing rights, the second when I try to remove the acl, -x invalid argument

Comment: I updated my answer with `rX` which should preserve listing permission